# Arsclassica: failure in Bibilography and minitoc

Tags: bibtex

I tried to use [`arsclassia`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/arsclassica/). I downloaded all the files, except the product, i.e. `ArsClassica.pdf`. I tried to compile `ArsClassica.tex` by TexShop, first LaTeX, then BiBTeX and 2 times LaTeX. When I did the BiBTeX, the error messages were:

```
"This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012);
I found no \citation commands---while reading file ArsClassica.aux;
I found no \bibdata commmand--- while reading file ArsClassica.aux;
I found no \bibstyle commmand--- while reading file ArsClassica.aux".
```

The resulting PDF file is identical to the `ArsClassica.pdf` file given in the above URL, except, there is no Bibliography and `minitoc`.
I am using this `arsclassia` package for my thesis and is now stuck.
Please advise what to do.

Comment: The document uses `biblatex`, so Biber should be used instead of BibTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have downloaded all the files from the last mentioned website and they were put in the correct directories in the identical way displayed in the website for ArsClassica. You can try the download and do not download the final pdf. The ArsClassica.tex file will after proper compilation should become the ArsClassica.pdf file (which is also available for download). But the compilation did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your class uses `biblatex`. The default backend of `biblatex` is `biber`. So you have to run `biber` instead of `bibtex`:

Compilation steps

```
(pdf)latex
biber
(pdf)latex
(pdf)latex
```

---

To get all needed file you should update your TeX distribution. Saving all needed files in the working directory is one of the worst things.

To update your system see: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)